# Diagnosing an additional redirect in a "Request initiator chain" when moving from localhost to a hosted site

Tags: http, redirect, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

I'm in the process of deploying my React site to AWS via Amplify, and the first step on the site is authenticating with Spotify. Here in their auth guide, they call the type of auth I am performing "[Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/)" where the first step is the site requesting a scoped auth and receiving a code via a http redirect.

This all works fine and dandy when I am running the app locally - the network logs and associated  looks like this (apologies, I'm not sure how to best reproduce for you this devtools output):

[localhost network  logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExmqQ.png)

[localhost initiator chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqIAO.png)

But when I attempt this on my live site [soundfound.io](https://soundfound.io) I instead receive in additional redirect which makes it impossible for me to retrieve the code (I believe at least - **I could not figure out a workaround** where I just capture the code from the 2nd 302 here but if you do, **please enlighten me** b/c I'm at the end of my rope here).

[live network logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTV3o.png)

[localhost initiator chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CpqO.png)

and here - my boilerplate AWS Amplify domain config: https://ibb.co/SV1N809

I've been reading up but this is just not clicking with me - WHO or WHAT is causing this additional redirect? It's certainly not the React application itself, that doesn't make any sense. Spotify knows about both redirect urls (localhost:3000/redirect and soundfound.io/redirect) so I don't understand how that could behave differently. The only place I can think to look is within the domain registration and control part of AWS Amplify - but I don't see (or don't understand) anything that would cause this sort of issue?

I'm just so lost as to where to begin trying to troubleshoot this, any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The AWS Amplify automatically creates a rule in the console App settings under "Rewrites and redirects" that redirects all requests to my base domain "soundfound.io" to "www.soundfound.io". Erasing this rule solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).